# Required product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

I am trying to understand why Magento keep marking product attributes as "Required Fields" on the product page, when I set its "Values Required" field to NO, in the Admin Panel.

Where else it's supposed to be changed that status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is mentioned in the [official Magento CE User Guide](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/attribute-create.html) regarding the **Values Required** property in

```
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute > [select attribute] > Attribute Properties
```

> To require that a value must be entered in the field before the record
>   can be saved, set Values Required to “Yes.”

What this does is that a product - which has this attribute assigned to it - can only be saved by the admin (when creating or editing the product) after a value for this attribute is entered. So basically this has nothing to do with the frontend.

Due to the nature of your question I assume we are dealing with a Configurable Product. It seems that you have selected this attribute as a configurable attribute (option) when creating the configurable product. Like in the image below.

[image: Magento Select Configurable Attributes]

Since each option is actually a separate, simple product, each of those options will be required in the frontend. Otherwise managing stock would not be possible.

If you would like to display options in the frontend that are not required you may consider using [Custom Options](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-options-custom.html) for your products and set **Is Required** to “No”.

[image: Magento Custom Options]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that clears up my doubts about it, but seems like it's not a real solution to my case, because I'll have to set too many aditional fields in order to set just one field: "is required". 

I would like to know if there's other way to avoid to select an attribute with just one value, but seems to me now that's not the case.

Comment: This actually is a totally different question. Therefore, you should ask a new question and explain - in detail - what you are trying to accomplish. Try to add some screen shots of your product page indicating what is your case.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, probably I'll do it, but I think that overriding some Magento code is the answer. Thanks for the advise.